# Store New Value In List of Variables, Specificly - Python3

Tags: python, arrays, list, variables

So, I'm working out a flagging system for emulating a CPU. Basically, I have this:

```
nFlag = False
vFlag = False
UFLAG = True
bFlag = True
DFLAG = False
iFlag = True
zFlag = False
cFlag = True

flags = [nFlag, vFlag, UFLAG, bFlag, DFLAG, iFlag, zFlag, cFlag]
```

And basically, I want to be able to overwrite the bool of the individual elements of the list/array depending of specific conditions. For example:

```
if condition == True:
    flags[0] = True
```

The expected outcome would be for nFlag to equal True but still remain in the list.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why keep separate variables? Just use the list items to test.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand what you mean here. I *think* you mean you want to change both the value of `nFlag` and its corresponding entry in the list at the same time.

The answer is no, you can't do that. But you don't want to. Instead of having separate variables, just use the list; or, even better, use a dictionary:

```
flags = dict(
    nFlag=False
    vFlag=False
    UFLAG=True
    bFlag=True
    DFLAG=False
    iFlag=True
    zFlag=False
    cFlag=True
)
```

Now you can do `flags['nFlag'] = True`, for example.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes a lot more sense, thank you. Yes, my intent was to retain the new value in "flags" without having to rewrite the list.

Answer (score 0):

No. Booleans are immutable (and singletons) in Python, and so boolean variables cannot be *updated* in the way you describe. A nicer implementation would be to use a dictionary, like

```
flags = {'nFlag': False, 'vFlag': False, 'UFLAG': True, 'bFlag': True, 'DFLAG': False, 'iFlag': True, 'zFlag': False, 'cFlag': True}
```

and then update the values like

```
if condition:  # Note: No need to compare explicitly to True
    flags['nFlag'] = True
```